# patsubst and dir usage

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to figure out what the following two lines in a .mk file mean

include $(ROOTDIRECT)/target/$(MYSUBDIR)/defs.mk
include $(ROOTDIRECT)/target/$(dir $(patsubst %/,%,$(MYSUBDIR)))/defs.mk

For clarity let ROOTDIRECT be "/home/me"  and MYSUBDIR be "platform"
The first line I guess is straight forward and includes "/home/me/target/platform/defs.mk"

The second line I dont understand and my guess from my environment is that  it includes "/home/me/target/defs.mk"
Am I right/wrong and could could someone help me to understand the second line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(patsubst %/,%,$(MYSUBDIR))` will substitute anything matching the pattern `%/` by `%`, where `%` can be anything.

In other words, it will remove the trailing `/` of `$(MYSUBDIR)`.

See GNU Make Manual [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions)